# tabcontrol validating when tabpage change

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I have tabcontrol with 3 tabpages in it. It always checks the validation when the tabpages of tabcontrol change.
I want to specifically check for validation on a certain tabpage only.

```
private void registration_tabcontrol_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!student_firstname_textbox.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
    {
        DialogResult res = XtraMessageBox.Show("DO YOU WANT TO CANCEL REGISTRATION?", "STUDENT REGISTRATION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {                        
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }              
    }  
}
```

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: sir how can i stop from validating when tabpage change

Comment: so, you want to check the validation for say suppose, only `tabPage1` and not on the other tabPages?

Comment: yes sir, do you have any idea to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I've added an answer to this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for an extra condition in your first `if`:

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1
```

The above line will check the validation specifically on your `tabPage1`.

```
private void registration_tabcontrol_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!student_firstname_textbox.Text.ToString().Equals("") && tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
    {
        DialogResult res = XtraMessageBox.Show("DO YOU WANT TO CANCEL REGISTRATION?", "STUDENT REGISTRATION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {                        
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }              
    }  
}
```

You can also check using:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0   //for tabPage1
```